# GOOGLE MAPS V2 - Get Current User Position

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to get user position, so far I'm able to get the 3 stores displayed on the map however i am unable to find my current position, this is done through and emulator, I have implemented the LocationListener method but it seems like the method (onLocationChaged) is never called, in the OnCreate method I have specified my 3 stores which display nicely on the map but not MY CURRENT LOCATION, I don't even have that "raider/round icon" at the top right to take me to my current location, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Java Code:

```
public class LocateStore extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

static final LatLng ARCADIA = new LatLng(-25.746318, 28.221322999999984);
static final LatLng HATFIELD = new LatLng(-25.7487333, 28.238043199999993);
static final LatLng CENTURION = new LatLng(-25.8602778, 28.189444399999957);
private GoogleMap map;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate_store);

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        Marker aracdia = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ARCADIA).title("Arcadia").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
        Marker hatfield = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HATFIELD).title("Hatfield").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
        Marker centurion = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CENTURION).title("Centurion").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_small)));
      }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         map.clear();

         MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

         mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

         mp.title("my position");

         map.addMarker(mp);

         map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
         new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 16));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: When you open the map you don't see a blue circle showing your location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled%28boolean%29)

Comment: OK, im sending GPS commands via geo fix in by telneting to localhost on port 5554 and the button takes me to coordinates received. Thanks a million.

Comment: This works in OnCreate, how do I make it work in the OnLocationChange because I see a small blue circle now but not my title position which is defined in the onLocationChanged method?

Answer (score 1):

try below code:-

```
        mapFragment         = (SupportMapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        map                 = mapFragment.getMap();

        map                 . setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You should provide a little explanation in addition to code.

Answer (score 0):

When testing on the emulator (i.e without a GPS chip or a network location) you have to enable mock locations. Have this in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
```

You then need to send the location by using the emulator control view in the DDMS perspective or by Telnet to the emulator, then with the geo fix command